# Multi-entities Business process flow

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I was asked to create BPF for my organization. After reading MSDN, TechNet, dynamics.com e.t.c. I start to work. So I create 1:N Relationship from task to my custom entity. Add lookups, mapping and BPF. Add handler for StageChange to create new record of custom entity.

```
this.setObjectForTask = function () {
            debugger
            var context = window.parent.Xrm.Page;
            var object = context.getAttribute("kr_object").getValue();
            var objectIsEmpty = (object == null || object == "undefined") ? true : false;

            if (!objectIsEmpty) {
                return;
            }

            var serverURL = window.parent.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
            var new_object = {};

            new_object["new_name"] = "Объект по заявке Ввод информационного листа";

            //var client = context.getAttribute("kr_client").getValue();
            //new_object["new_customer"] = [{
            //    id: client[0].id,
            //    name: client[0].name,
            //    entityType: client[0].entityType
            //}];

            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("POST", serverURL + "/api/data/v8.1/new_objectses", true);
            req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
            req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
            req.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 /* complete */) {
                    req.onreadystatechange = null;
                    if (this.status == 204) {
                        debugger
                        var new_objectUri = this.getResponseHeader("OData-EntityId");
                        var ID = new_objectUri.substr(new_objectUri.length - 38).substring(1, 37); //GUID 
                        window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("kr_object").setValue([{
                            id: ID,
                            name: "",
                            entityType: "new_objects"
                        }]);
                        console.log(ID);
                    } else {
                        var error = JSON.parse(this.response).error;
                        alert(error.message);
                    }
                }
            };
            req.send(JSON.stringify(new_object));
    };
```

And nothing happens! Even with lookup point to new record of custom entity, I can't proceed to the next stage.
Please explain me: How this feature should be set to work with records of multiply entities?!
Thank you.

Comment: Why `window.parent` ?